# Как распаковать файл из нескольких аривов?

Tags: tar, ubuntu

Я скачал 5 архивов (tar.xz.##). В них находится, как я понял, один файл с данными. Как распаковать файл из нескольких аривов? ОС - Ubuntu 10.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
cat *.tar.xz.** > all.tar.xztar -xJpf all.tar.xz
```

Также возможен вариант с конвеером.